# Inserting a common text/box inside all the tabPanels of a navbarMenu in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, navbar, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to create an Rshiny application and I'm stuck with inserting a common value inside all the tabs of a navbarmenu. When I'm trying it is getting inserted to all the tabs which are not even a part of the navbarMenu.

Can somebody suggest me a solution? than you in advance

This is my code

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("variable", "Select an SKU:", materials, selected = '')
),
mainPanel(
navbarPage("DEMAND PREDICTION!",
           theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
           tabPanel("Home",
                    h1("Time series forecasting"),
                    verbatimTextOutput("summary_1")
           ),
           tabPanel("Histogram",
                    fluidRow(column(3,
                                    wellPanel(selectInput("variable", "Select an SKU:", materials, selected = ''),
                                              selectInput("market", "Select a market:", choices = NULL)
                                    ))
                    ),
                    mainPanel(
                        plotlyOutput("hist"),
                        h4("Sales per Country"),plotOutput("map")
                    )),
           navbarMenu("Exploratory Analysis",
                      tabPanel("Line graph",
                               plotlyOutput("exploratory")),
                      tabPanel("Box plot", plotlyOutput("boxplot")),
                      tabPanel("Seasonal plot", plotlyOutput("seasonal")),
                      fluidRow(column(3,"hello")))
           
           )))
```

This is just an overview of my code. Here inside the navbar menu I'm trying to add a common field that can be reflected in all panels within the navbarMenu. Instead it is shown in other tabs which are not even a part of navbarMenu.

Comment: Could you share the code you tried?

Comment: I have added the code. Any help or suggestion would be really helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the code. What text do you want to insert, where do you want it to be displayed?

Comment: I'm not trying to insert a text, rather trying to insert a common textbox say for example. And I want it to be common for all tabs inside the "navbarMenu"